# How can I make sure a window always showing above soft keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I add a view by WindowManager above soft keyboard with TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL, but it doesn't work on some phones, neither TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT. What should I do to make it happen on all phones?

Comment: Do you mean "over" or "above" (or on top of the soft keyboard)?

Comment: on top of soft keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

`TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` windows do not work on some devices at all, but if they work they should be placed above the IME window. I would recommend you to try `TYPE_TOAST` windows. Toasts work on all devices and are shown above keyboard. But on some Android versions like 4.1 toasts do not accept user input such as touches or key events.

`TYPE_PHONE` might also be a good candidate for solving your problem but I think it will not work on devices where `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` doesn't work.

**UPDATE**: Another thing you may try is to add `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM` to `WindowManager.LayoutParams.flags`. This flag tells Android to position a window so that it can cover IME. In this case `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag must be unset. In this configuration the window will be focusable and should be positioned in front of IME.

Another option is to have just `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag set and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM` flag unset. It will also make your window positioned in front of IME but the window will not be focusable.